# Using a file to store json data

Tags: angularjs, json, database, web-applications, nosql

I am working on a webapp for a client that has a cPanel virtual server, and it appears that I can only use MySQL, but I want to store the data using a json-like structure, so that I can more easily use Angular.js on the frontend.

I've looked into installing a NoSQL database, and I can't find anything viable (if you know of a way to do that, that would be my best solution), so I'm thinking of storing the data as json strings in a series of text files on the server that I would write to with php.

I'd like to hear some opinions, and if there are any better solutions of which I'm not thinking of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go look at firebase and thank me afterwards.

In short, firebase is a cloud real-time JSON data storage.  Everything for the backend is done for you and all you need to do is the front-end.  Their servers are CDNs which means it will be great if you're looking to serve the entire world.  All you need to do is configure your data-structure and use it!

It also provides sockets, which is great for real-time data (used for games, chat and etc).

There is a free option.  The only downside is that it is a little expensive if you want to scale it, nevertheless if your app really gets to that stage - I'm sure you'll have money to hire some people to develop a similar backend for yourself.

Comment: Ooo.. This is pretty nifty. I don't see enough benefit in this for my current project, since I'm not doing much/any real-time operations, but this is def something that I will keep in mind for future projects. Thanks! :)

Comment: Doesnt have to be real time applications, you can also set it up for restful apis